# MomentJS Timezone - Local input time to GMT+2

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to convert a user inputted time from local time to GMT+1 using MomentJS Timezone, however, I have never used this library before and the documentation rather confuses me.

My form uses Bootstrap Datepicker and Bootstrap timepicker to create a UI for inputting the date and time of an event, like this:

```
    <label>Date:</label>
    <input type="text" id="dteDay">
    <input type="hidden" id="iptDate">
    <label>Time (GMT+1 only):</label>
    <input id="iptTime" type="text">

   <script>
    $("#dteDay").datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        todayHighlight: true,
        startDate: "-2d",
        endDate: "+0d",
    });


    $('#iptTime').timepicker({
        minuteStep: 5,
        showMeridian: false
    });
    </script>
```

Then I use this function to collect the date and time to send to a PHP file, like so:

```
function CreateReport(){        
        if( $("#sltMyName").select2("val") == null ){
            ShowError("Please Enter Your Name!");
        }
        else if( $("#sltTheirName").select2("val") == null ){
            ShowError("Please Enter Their Name!");
        }
        else if( $("#dteDay").val() == "" ){
            ShowError("Please Enter the Date of Incident!");
        }
        else if( $("#iptTime").val() == "" ){
            ShowError("Please Enter the Time of Incident!");
        }
        else if( $("#txtStory").val() == "" ){
            ShowError("Please Enter the Full Story!");
        }
        else if( $("#txtEvidence").val() == "" ){
            ShowError("Please List your Evidence");
        }
        else{
            if( $("#sltOffence").val() == "Other" && $("#iptOtherOffence").val() == ""){
                ShowError("Please Enter Offence");
            }
            else if( $("#sltOffence").val() == "Other" ){
                var Offence = $("#iptOtherOffence").val();
            }
            else{
                var Offence = $("#sltOffence").val();
            }
            $.post(
                'includes/complaint/index.php',
                {
                    Server: $("#sltServerRegion").val(),
                    MyName: JSON.stringify($("#sltMyName").select2("val")),
                    TheirName: JSON.stringify($("#sltTheirName").select2("val")),
                    Date: $("#dteDay").val(),
                    Time: $("#iptTime").val(),
                    Offence: Offence,
                    Story: $("#txtStory").val(),
                    Evidence: $("#txtEvidence").val(),
                    RefundAmount: $("#iptRefundAmount").val(),
                    RefundPreference: $("#sltRefundPreference").val()
                },
                function(data){
                    returnValue = JSON.parse(data);
                    if( returnValue["data"] == 1){
                        window.location.href = returnValue["url"];
                    }
                    else{
                        ShowError(returnValue["msg"]);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

What I need to do is change the inputted time into GMT+1 (or preferably GMT+2 in summer) to match the time our other system uses.

I understand with MomentJS Timezone you can turn a date to specific timezone, like so:

```
var newYork = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
```

Although I don't understand this much. It converts it from what (ie, GMT+1) to New_York?

In short, how do I convert a user inputted time from local time to GMT+1 (or in summer GMT+2 if possible) then split them against to pass to the AJAX function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "or in summer GMT+2 if possible" ?

Comment: When the clocks go forward an hour when we change from GMT+1 to GMT+2.

Comment: This change is implicit. When the clocks go forward of an hour, they go forward in all the World. So if you retrieve a current date with a timezone and you convert it to another timezone, they already bring this change back

Comment: I guess. Timezone "science" confuse me to be honest.

Comment: @quirimmo - No, absolutely do they not go forward in all the world.  The world is complex, and time zones vary significantly across the world.  Many countries do not use daylight saving time, and those that do all do it slightly differently.

Comment: @MattJohnson ok so I didn't know how daylight saving time works. Can you give me an example of a country where they don't put hours forward?

Comment: @quirimmo - Lots.  India, for one.  [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) shows a map that addresses that quite well.  Also, you'll find a lot of information at timeanddate.com, such as [this page](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2017.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert from local time to a fixed UTC offset, you do not need the moment-timezone add-on at all.  You can do this with Moment.js by itself.  For example:

```
var m = moment("2017-01-01 00:00:00");    // input is local time
m.utcOffset('+01:00');                    // convert to UTC+1
var s = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");  // output string
```

However, since you asked for converting from local time to a time zone that switches between UTC+1 and UTC+2 for daylight saving time, then you must indeed use moment-timezone.  But first, you must choose the correct time zone for your destination - not every time zone that switches between +1 and +2 do it on the same day or at the same time of day.  Don't just pick one at random.  A list of them can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

One such time zone would be `Europe/Paris`, which uses European Union rules for DST to switch from UTC+1 (CET) to UTC+2 (CEST)

```
var m = moment("2017-01-01 00:00:00");    // input is local time
m.tz('Europe/Paris');                     // convert to UTC+1
var s = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");  // output string
```

Also, in your question, you asked what the example was converting from.  It wasn't converting at all - it was treating the input as `America/New_York` time.  Since you want to start at local time, you wouldn't use `moment.tz(...)` to construct a moment, you'd use `.tz(...)` on an existing local moment instead.

One more thing - another answer suggested changing the default time zone.  That will not actually solve your problem.  In fact, it will prevent you from achieving what you described - because then all your input will be treated as time within that time zone, not the local time zone of the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

It changes the given date time `2014-06-01 12:00` from the default timezone in the World (GMT), to the provided one. 
You can also change your default one using:

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");
```

This is the list of the default timezones you can use as strings in moment timezone:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

You can also use moment and the utcOffset method instead:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/

Comment: How could I set the default to the local time then to turn local time to GMT+1?

Comment: `moment.tz.setDefault("Africa/Brazzaville");` should make the trick

Comment: Yeh, that turns the time from GMT to GMT+2, however how can I change the timezone it turns from to GMT+2? As I want to do Local Time (for any user) -> GMT+2 and not GMT -> GMT+2.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't understand very well what you want to do. 
Actually you want to convert all dates to GMT+2?

Comment: Yeh. The user needs to enter the date and time of an event in their timezone (which is any timezone) and we need to convert it to GMT+2 as that's what our other systems use.

Comment: I think you're struggling with the concept of the World timezone :) 
If I get the current date in JavaScript on my system (Italy) the system already knows itself the GMT. This is the output:
`Tue May 09 2017 22:01:59 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`
With `.getTimezoneOffset()` method, you have the difference between the actual tz and the default one. In my case: `-60`
You can open your console and try it yourself.
So, considering you are using moment, if you use the code above (`moment.tz.setDefault()`), you have by default all moment dates of the given timezone (GMT +2 in your case)

Comment: Ok I understand a lot more now about the timezone stuff, thanks. However, your description of how to actually complete the original task confuses me, do you mean `moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "Africa/Brazzaville");` will change any timezone to GMT+2? The issue is I am not using `Date()` to collect the date, so the thing will have no `GMT+0100` on the end, so I doubt that method will work. Is there another way I can obtain the user's timezone to append to the date to provide that info?

Comment: No the code you posted convert your date "2014-06-01 12:00" considered as default GMT to the GMT+2 Africa/Brazzaville.
This line tells moment to use as default date the GMT+2
moment.tz.setDefault("Africa/Brazzaville");
So if you change it, and then get the current date with moment, you will see that it is on GMT+2

Comment: I think I have it now can you confirm my understanding. Using moment.tz.setDefault("Africa/Brazzaville"); I change the user's local time to GMT+2, now when I create a moment with the inputted date and time `moment("2014-06-01 12:00");` It will output this moment in GMT+2? Obviously, it's hard to test this as I can't fly around the place so I want to check I have this 100% nailed. Thanks for your help, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason why it wouldn't work when using a custom format? I am doing `moment.tz.setDefault("Africa/Brazzaville"); DateTime = moment($("#dteDay").val()+' '+ $("#iptTime").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');`, however it's not moving it forward an hour.

Comment: Sure my answer to your previous question was not precise. Updating that and prepared you a jsfiddle to explain you how it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/vn46wbcs/

Comment: Answering to your question. If you specify your default tz, all the dates CREATED with moment will refer to the provided tz. So if you ask for current date with moment(), you will have the right one for the tz you specified. 
BUT, if you pass your date, moment doesn't apply any change because it thinks that you are already using your default timezone. 
From what I understood, you just need to transform all your date to a tz. 
So not use a default one, just call after every date `moment(date).tz('Africa/Brazzaville')
`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I can work it out from here, you have been of great help.

Comment: It was actually a lot of work and I am yet to test it properly. Seemingly when you `.format()` a date it converts it to local unless `.utc(date)./*other functions*/.format()` is used, however if `.utc()` is used then I have to use an offset (`.utcOffset("+0200")`). which currently does not change automatically depending on Day light saving time, so it will require manual updated currently, which isn't ideal. `DateTime = moment.utc(moment($("#dteDay").val()+' '+ $("#iptTime").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')).utcOffset("+0200").format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");`

Comment: I am at work now, I'll brb to you asap once stopped working :) 
just a flash thing. Correct, when you use moment by default it uses default utc. 
Consider that moment utcOffset is the equivalent of moment tz, actually they do the same. I would suggest you to create some utility which wraps your methods, so you don't have to put all this code everywhere. 
So create your own method and inside it perform the `moment(data).utcOffset("+0200").format("DD/MM/YYY HH:mm");`

Comment: This is where I got the understanding about format from: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/ along with other experimenting. It seems that everything worked with `.tz()` to change the timezone up until the `.format()`, which would put it back into local time for some reason. According to that link when using `.utc()` it will not change it back to local on any output. I did try `moment.utc(moment($("#dteDay").val()+' '+ $("#iptTime").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')).tz('Africa/Brazzaville').format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");`, but it changed it back to local despite being created with `.utc()`.

Comment: In regards to making a function / utility to do the whole process, there's little point as it's only a very small project and it's only used once (possibly twice, but will vary as that will be to convert to our NA server timezone.)

Comment: for the format after the tz, have you tried to keep the tz default definition before to call the format method?
About moving everything to the server I totally agree. Your best choice at the moment seems to be that you send to the server all the dates how they are by default and convert all of them to the tz you would like

Comment: FYI - It's a little silly to choose `Africa/Brazzaville` unless you are explicitly targeting Congo.

Comment: Also, sorry for the downvote, but your answer doesn't solve the problem asked.  Changing the default time zone removes the ability to treat the input as the local time zone of the user, which was part of the question.

Comment: @MattJohnson Nothing for the downvote, you don't have to apologize. btw about the solution, if you read all the comments, my suggestion was to keep the default one, get the time in the current default timezone of the system, and convert it to the one you want to use. About the country to use, I just said that moment timezone use as strings a huge list of countries that you can find on wikipedia too (and I posted the link to them, and they have the same link in their website) and I used that one because it was the first in the list with GMT +2. Just for that. But living in Congo would be great.

Comment: Sure, just keep in mind that the point of StackOverflow is not just to respond to the question asked, but to provide quality answers to quality questions, such that others may benefit from them as well.  I don't think the question was asked well, but at least the answer should match what was asked.  Anyway, cheers and thanks to you and well wishes.